# What is the reverse mathematical strength of the assumption of the existence of a nontrivial ultrafilter?

Tags: logic, reverse-math

I'm new to studying reverse math, how strong is the statement of the existence of a nontrivial ultrafilter on $\omega$? Does it have the same strength as one of the big 5 subsystems, or does it lie outside of them?

Here's another asked questions that was similar, but seemingly from a different perspective.
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258310/how-strong-is-the-existence-of-a-non-trivial-ultrafilter-on-omega

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse mathematics is the wrong tool for this: it takes place in the context of second-order arithmetic (= natural numbers and sets of natural numbers) and so the existence of an ultrafilter (= a set of sets of natural numbers with certain properties) can't even be stated directly in the language.

Expanding reverse math to broader languages is the task of **higher reverse mathematics**. In this context, [Henry Towsner showed](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.3902) that the existence of an ultrafilter is conservative over the theory ACA$_0$ (and a number of other facts).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I have much to learn. I will look into higher reverse mathematics at some point.